# Can't find button and click

Tags: ruby

Got a button that changes state when clicked on.  But, I cannot "find the button, even when in it's default state.:

**Source code:**

```
 <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="show_cd_only">
 <div class="btn btn-inverse" ng-click="requestCD()">Only Disclose Via  CD</div>
 <p>Click here to specify that all future disclosures for this loan should be sent via CD instead of LE. If a CD has already been sent, no LEs will be sent regardless of this button action.</p>
</div>
```

**Page Object Source:**

```
class ClosingValidationsReportsPage < GenericBasePage
include DataHelper

element(:onlyDiscloseViaCD) {|b| b.button(xpath: "//div[@id='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span/div/div")}
element(:allowLEDisclosures) {|b| b.button(xpath: "//div[@id='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span/div[2]/div")}
element(:message) {|b| b.element(xpath: "(//div[@id='flash']/div)[2]")}

end
```

**Selenium-Cucumber source:**

```
And(/^you click on Only Disclose Via CD button$/) do
on(ClosingValidationsReportsPage).onlyDiscloseViaCD.when_present.hover
on(ClosingValidationsReportsPage).onlyDiscloseViaCD.when_present.click
end
```

**Results:**

```
 Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:xpath=>"//div[@id='main']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span/div/div", :tag_name=>"button"} to become present
 ./features/step_definitions/closing_interaction.rb:91:in `/^you click on Only Disclose Via CD button$/'
 ./features/CTMWEB-5238-CTM Web - Closing Validation Screen - Disclosure Indicator.feature:9:in `And you click on Only Disclose Via CD button'
```

**Button States:**

[image]

Second state pops up a message that I would need to assert is present once buttons is clicked.

Comment: You need to show us HTML that is presented in the page (the actual 'code' in 'source code'.  Only then can we figure out what's wrong with trying to work with it.  Right now we only have half the picture.  Thanks.

Comment: Also recommend you play around finding the element in the browser console and be sure you have a methods that works from there.

Comment: HTML for this was already in the question- however due to poor formatting it was not showing up. I have re-formatted it, and now HTML is visible in the question.

Comment: What if you define it as an element instead of a button, does your code see it then? I mean this part "b.button()".

Comment: Yeah, thanks Dave, I tried all those things.  It's perplexing, because it "should" work as it is.

Comment: I would try defining it as a div and failing that, switch to a different selector like css.

Comment: You beat me to it.  Just hopped in to answer my own question and you had the same solution.  Thank you, sir!